# Custom EditProfile.aspx Page in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: development, my-site

I have a custom "EditProfile.aspx" page under the path "/_layouts/CustomFeature/", want to use this page instead of the default "EditProfile.aspx" page. Where I have to make the change so that Mysite will use my custom page?

Comment: I mean, when user clicks on the edit profile link is on the view profile page on the MYSITE, it has to use my page instead of the default page.

Comment: do not want to hard code the URL anywhere.

Comment: shall we try with set-spcustomlayoutspage commend?

Comment: Replace the existing one with your custom page but keep in mind some patches/updates/upgrades can replace your custom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an httphandler where you could catch when a request is done on the exising editprofile.aspx page and redirect to your own .

you will find here some code for doing that

http://gilleslauwers.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/sharepoint-2010%E2%80%B2s-upload-multiple-documents-in-silverlight-part-2/

gl